# Take screenshots in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of my iOS application when it is running in the simulator, and save the screenshot on my Mac. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1033, accepted):

It's just as simple as <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or `File` > `Save Screen Shot` in iOS Simulator. It will appear on your desktop by default.

Comment: How do I get it to prompt me for the location to save to?

Comment: There is no ready-to-use solution as per http://stackoverflow.com/q/23661097/1659311

Comment: UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification did not fire.

Comment: In Xcode 9 you can hold down Option and you will be prompted for a location to save the screenshot.

Comment: @jameshfisher - This may help you to get prompt for location to save - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48150656/5638630

Comment: Heads up, it won't prompt you to save so check your desktop after hitting save.

Comment: Its not coming on my desktop :(

Comment: @AshimDahal it's still is on Xcode 10.2.1 - I've just checked. Make sure you have Simulator active, not Xcode itself.

Comment: @WojciechRutkowski for some reason none of my shortcuts was not working ..... I had to toggle switch in Simulator --> Hardware--> Keyboard --> Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Device. This fixed all my shortcut functionality to work normally

Comment: If the screen shot is to be used on the app store, it can't have alpha, and the default is to have alpha 'on'.  So that means bringing the image up in the preview and exporting without alpha.  That a PITA.  Thanks Apple.

Comment: Check ~/Downloads if your screenshots are not in ~/Desktop

Answer (score 162):

An update with Xcode 11.4 simulator

To capture a screen shot, click on  'Camera' icon/action button, on the top bar of simulator.

[image]

OR

Select `Save Screen Shot` menu item, from `File` menu.

File => Save Screen Shot

---

Use <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd> to capture a screen shot.

(Use <kbd>window + s</kbd>, if you are using windows/non-apple keyboard).

[image]

See for more details: [How to change simulator scale options with Xcode 9+.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481412/changing-ipad-iphone-simulator-resolution-for-xcode-4-3-2/46668618#46668618)

---

**Tip 1: How do you get screen shot with 100% (a scale with actual device size) that can be uploaded on AppStore?**

**Disable** `Optimize Rendering for Window scale` from `Debug` menu, before you take a screen shot.

Here is an option

> Menubar  ▶  Debug  ▶  Disable "Optimize Rendering for Window scale"

[image]

---

**Tip 2: Where is screen shot saved (Default Path)? How to change default path?**

Simulator saves screen shot file on (logged-in user's) desktop and it's default path.

To change default path (with Xcode 9+), press and hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> (alt) button from keyboard, while you take a screen shot. 
Or 

Using Mac Keyboad: Press keys <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>   + <kbd>⌘</kbd>   + <kbd>s</kbd> all together. 

It will show to a dialog with file storage options and also allows to set/change default path.

[image]

---

**Tip 3: How to take a screen shot with Device Bezel?**

Enable `Show Device Bezel` from `Window` menu.

Here is an option

> Menubar  ▶  Window  ▶  Enable "Show Device Bezel"

[image]

Now,

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, all together in Mac Keyboard. (A window snap capture mode will become active)
2. Select `Simulator` window/frame, that you want to capture. It will save screenshot with device bezel (with shadow effect in background) on (logged-in user's) desktop.

You can also remove the Simulator toolbar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61657770/2870968).

Comment: Also, hold ⌘ when you click on the simulator to skip the device name on the bottom in the screenshot.

Comment: @ManojShrestha You are welcomed to edit this answer by adding your suggestion.

Comment: Why is this NOT accepted answer. Thanks a ton Krunal for this compilation!

Comment: I liked this answer.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore after latest (11.4) Xcode update

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu - Thank you for the update. You are welcomed to edit this answer and improve its quality. (I'll check and update, if I'll get a chance)

Comment: Also, hold the Alt key while clicking on the simulator for taking screenshots without shadows.

Answer (score 40):

on iOS Simulator,

Press `Command + control + c` or from menu : `Edit>Copy Screen`

open "Preview" app, Press `Command + n` or from menu : File> New from clipboard
, then you can save `command+s`

> For Retina, activate iOS Simulator then on menu:`HardWare>Device>iPhone (Retina)`
>   and follow above process

```
Command + S
```

is the way to save on Desktop, (on new iPhone simulators, this was introduced in later simulator)

Answer (score 30):

Press `Command+Shift+4` and then keep the mouse pointer on Simulator and then press `"Space Bar"` key one camera icon will appear, now `left click` the mouse. Your simulator screen shot is saved on desktop. You can take the screen shot any small screen in the same way.

Comment: this will not capture scrolled content though

Comment: You should only do this if you want to capture a screenshot with the bezel.

Comment: Nice, I wanted the frame too so great solution :)

Answer (score 16):

You can google for IOS Simulator Cropper software useful for capturing screen shots and also easy to use with various options of taking snapshots like with simulator/without simulator.

**Update**
Just pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will give you screenshot saved on desktop. Pretty easy huh..

Answer (score 15):

Since Xcode 8.2, you can also save a screenshot with the following command:

`xcrun simctl io booted screenshot`

Further information in this blog: https://medium.com/@hollanderbart/new-features-in-xcode-8-2-simulator-fc64a4014a5f#.bzuaf5gp0

Comment: The crash was a framework bug that we worked around in Xcode 8.3.3. It does not apply to Xcode 9 or later.

Answer (score 14):

1. Focus simulator
2. Go to menu **File->Save Screen Shot**

   or

   Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Screen shot saves in desktop

Answer (score 14):

*Simple answer with sample answer ;-)*

on iOS Simulator,

Press **Command + control + c** or from **menu : Edit>Copy Screen**

[image]

open "**Preview**" app, **Press Command + n** or from menu : **File> New** from clipboard , then you can **save Command + s**

> **UnCheck Alpha**

[image]

You can change Image dimension to your requirement.

[image]

> **Here is the Final Image,For example**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For people using Xcode 11.4, to get rid of the simulator top bar, this is far from ideal but you can disable shadows for the screenshot application in a terminal with the following command :

```
$ defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool TRUE; killall SystemUIServer
```

Then, you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> and select the simulator to take a screenshot. Without the shadow, you can easily crop the top bar with the preview app. To re-enable the shadow for the screenshot application :

```
$ defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool FALSE; killall SystemUIServer
```

Source of this answer [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/131139).

Answer (score 4):

For some reason the commands posted before dont work for me, but this one does:

```
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot screenshot.png
```

Running Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 3):

First, run the app on simulator.
Then, use **command**+**s**, or **File** -> **Save Screenshot** in Simulator to take necessary and appropriate shots.
The screenshots will appear on your desktop by default.

Answer (score 3):

### 2020 Latest Update: XCode 11.4

Click on the **camera icon above simulator** to capture screenshot and save to your camera roll

[image]

Another option:
**File > Save Screen** from simulator

Comment: it takes screenshots without device frame

Comment: seems like the "command" key to remove the device name at the bottom doesn't work anymore, bummer. Need to manually crop the top out.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>⌘S</kbd> or go to **File > Save screenshot** from your simulator menu and you will get the screenshot saved on your desktop.

Comment: Oh my mistake this will be possible only if you are running MAC using VMWare

Comment: Thanks Devang. May i will try it for VMWare.

Answer (score 2):

In OSX Captain its a bug to take screenshot of simulator. You have to Update your OSX Sierra first then your are able to take. while taking in OSX Captain use terminal command which is **xcrun simctl io booted screenshot**.

before running this command u have to select desktop in terminal like:

"cd desktop" then run that command. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

Screenshot with device frame

**Step - 1**
Open quick time player

**Step - 2**
Tap new screen recording

[image]

**Step - 3**
Select Capture selected window
[image]

**Step - 4**
Cursor point on the simulator. It will automatically select the whole simulator like
[image]

**Step - 5**
Screenshot will open using preview. save it.

Here is some sample screenshot

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but when I take the snapshot, it also captures the bar that is above the iPhone with the close/minimize/full screen buttons, as well as the capture, home, and rotate buttons.  How do I capture just the phone without this bar?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click CMD+SHIFT+4.
2. Put mouse over Simulator.
3. Press SPACE to select whole Window.
4. Press ALT+Enter to capture simulator window with no shadow.
5. Remove top bar from screenshot in GIMP or double click on screenshot preview to edit.

I found no way to hide top window bar and screenshot nice phone image with shadow. Apple rox ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach the device frame to your screenshot, use

```
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot shot.png && curl -F 'file=@shot.png' "https://shot.withfra.me/new"
```

It uploads the screenshot to a third party (WithFrame) that adds the device frame.

More info can be found [here](https://withfra.me/shot)

Answer (score 0):

**First method:**

Select simulator and press "***command + s***" button. Screenshot saved on desktop.

**Second method:**

Select simulator and go to "***File > New Screenshot***". Screenshot saved on desktop.

Comment: What have you added to this question that was worth resurrecting a years old question?

Answer (score 0):

In case using XCUITests automation :

```
XCUIApplication().buttons["Add"].screenshot()
XCUIApplication().table["names"].screenshot()
```

API details : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiscreenshot

Answer (score -2):

Taking Screen Shot in IOS Simulator is SO Simple.

When you Open Simulator In the Right Lift You See File.

Click On File And You See Option Save Screen Shot.

This Option Saves Your Screen Shot In Default Path Which is Desktop.

Comment: This is more or less just a repeat of the existing answers.

Comment: @Pang no this one is way more condescending, to get the point across of course.