# Changing iPad/iPhone simulator resolution for Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator, screen-resolution

I am working on a Philips 19" and upgraded Xcode to version 4.3.2. 
On the new "Retina Display" on iPad 3 (oh, sorry, on The New iPad) my iPad simulator changes it's resolution and the simulator has vertical and horizontal scroll bars!

How do I change the resolution of the an iOS simulator?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following hotkeys should be helpful:

- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (100%)
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> (75%)
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> (50%)
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> (33%)
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> (25%)

Look at menu: "Window --> Scale" to see the options.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the retina display using - Hardware -> Device -> iPad

You can press `cmd` + 1 or `cmd` + 2 or `cmd` + 3 to change the size of the simulator. It will load the retina images but use a smaller simulator so you don't have to scroll for your testing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `cmd+1`, `cmd+2` and `cmd+3` options under `Window->Scale` that zoom to 100%, 75% and 50% respectively, you can also kind of do a custom zoom amount by setting a custom preference. Namely, try setting the `SimulatorWindowLastScale` preference in the `com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist` file under `~/Library/Preferences` directory. Running the following command in a terminal worked for me to be able to see the full screen of an iPad Air with iOS Simulator 8.2:

`defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.4"`

See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/93313

Comment: Thank you for additional info :)

Answer (score 1):

In the menu bar:

Hardware -> Device -> iPad

Answer (score 0):

You can also in Simulator -> Window to choose the Physical Size, which will make the size as large as the iPhone physical size:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The shortcut key is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>