# can simulator screenshots for ios app store result in metadata rejection?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ios-simulator, screenshot

Info from review:

We noticed that your marketing screenshot(s) do not sufficiently reflect your app in use. Specifically, they only display the splash screen. In addition, they reflect your app running on an iOS simulator. We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

I can make more shots, but that "In addition ..." Is it not allowed to use simulator for screenshots? I have only iPad2 but my app is universal, I do not have 4 different iPhones.

Did anybody get reject because of simulator screenshots?

Comment: no they will never reject your app due to simulator screen shot

Comment: i used simulator screen shot for my app for publishing

Comment: "they only display the splash screen", just take screenshots of functional part of your application

Answer (score 3):

We have published many applications and we ALWAYS used simulator screenshots (cmd-S).

Just make sure they are in the correct resolution since you can scale and optimize rendering for scale, it can produce incorrect resolution in your screenshots

Note that officially Apple asks that you take the screenshots on the device tough: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html

> Take screenshots on the target device (not in iOS Simulator)

Comment: well, it seems like they do require screenshots taken on real devices. that is ridiculous, I need to get me 4 iPhones and iPad pro? How do you like them apples.

Comment: as I said tough, we never did and never will take screenshots on real devices. If you must tough, there are QA services that have all the devices and can produce them

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I got rejected few times and later only understood that via the simulator we can have screenshots with cmd+S command conveniently. And that gives us the exact resolution for the device we simulate. The review team would have mentioned this, but never did. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd> to capture a screen shot.

(Use <kbd>window + s</kbd>, if you are using windows/non-apple keyboard).

[image]

See for more details: [How to change simulator scale options with Xcode 9+.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481412/changing-ipad-iphone-simulator-resolution-for-xcode-4-3-2/46668618#46668618)

---

**Answer to your question:** *How do you get screen shot with 100% (a scale with actual device size) that can be uploaded on AppStore?*

**Disable** `Optimize Rendering for Window scale` from `Debug` menu, before you take a screen shot.

Here is an option

> Menubar  ▶  Debug  ▶  Disable "Optimize Rendering for Window scale"

[image]