# Take screenshot in iPhone Simulator in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, screenshot, xcode9

How can I take screenshot of size 1242 x 2208 (required for App Store) from iPhone 8 Plus simulator in Xcode 9.0? I can't resize the simulator like we did in earlier versions of Xcode. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: scale the simulator to 100% then press `⌘` + `s`; the screenshot in the right size will be on your desktop.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as well.

Comment: Whats the problem with -> scale the simulator to **100%** then press `⌘` +`s` ?

Answer (score 61):

I have met the similar problem and here is the solution. 
**Uncheck** "**Optimize Rendering for Window Scale**" option from "**Debug**" menu.
Then take your screenshot(**Cmnd + S**) with zoom. Now it will be in size **1242 x 2208**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Spend 30 min on this problem :/ Apple should stop changing his things every 6 month...

Comment: I was struggling with this, and apart from unchecking this setting also make sure that you have the 6s plus hardware selected. I was using 6s hardware and it wasn't getting me the right resolution.

Comment: Xcode 10: Use the correct iPhone Simulators (e.g. 6.5" iPhone Xs Max, 5.5" iPhone 8 Plus) and hit `command-s` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297870/wrong-screenshot-size-in-xcode-10-using-simulator

Answer (score 30):

Use <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd> to capture a screen shot.

(Use <kbd>window + s</kbd>, if you are using windows/non-apple keyboard).

[image]

See for more details: [How to change simulator scale options with Xcode 9+.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481412/changing-ipad-iphone-simulator-resolution-for-xcode-4-3-2/46668618#46668618)

---

**Tip 1: How do you get screen shot with 100% (a scale with actual device size) that can be uploaded on AppStore?**

**Disable** `Optimize Rendering for Window scale` from `Debug` menu, before you take a screen shot.

Here is an option

> Menubar  ▶  Debug  ▶  Disable "Optimize Rendering for Window scale"

[image]

---

**Tip 2: How to take a screen shot with Device Bezel?**

Enable `Show Device Bezel` from `Window` menu.

Here is an option

> Menubar  ▶  Window  ▶  Enable "Show Device Bezel"

[image]

Now,

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, all together in Mac Keyboard. (A window snap capture mode will become active)
2. Select `Simulator` window/frame, that you want to capture. It will save screenshot with device bezel (with shadow effect in background) on (logged-in user's) desktop.

Answer (score 4):

I tried and can take screenshot of size 1242 x 2208(required for App Store) from iPhone 8 Plus simulator in XCode 9.0 by steps below.

- Open your simulator
- Double click on toolbar of your simulator
- Command + S

The saved screenshot will have right dimensions. It works with every simuator.

[image]

Comment: This only works in some situations, depending on simulated device size and  computers resolution. Disabling "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale" (arunjos's answer) always works. (I didn't downvote, though)

Comment: @quemeful It's mine. Any problem here?

Comment: see the answer below, that's how all simulators look nowadays I thought

Comment: @quemeful You can see iOS version is 11.1. It’s XCode 9. You can change the interface on setting. As I remember it’s Show device bezels ;)

Comment: This information is relevant only if your target is not iOS 17. However, if your aim is iOS 17, you may encounter limitations as the iOS 17 runtime is unavailable for any of the 5.5" devices, including iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, and iPhone 8 Plus.

Answer (score 3):

Please use different iPhone Plus screen and make sure that is "Pixel Accurate"
 (click on *Window* and set *Pixel Accurate*).