# Wrong screenshot size in Xcode 10 using Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I'm trying to make screenshots for iTunes using the Xcode 10 Simulator, but the images are the wrong size.

I have read that `Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale` would help, but in Xcode there is no such option. Does anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing, it looks like Xcode 10.0 has full resolution screenshot ability for iPhone X series simulators only. It's good to know that it is enough to make 6.5" screen size screenshots to submit to the App Store, so just use iPhone X series simulators for screenshots to solve the issue.

Comment: For me, I was able to take screenshots with iphone 8 plus simulator, otherwise it didnt work ....

Comment: Regular iPhone X does not give a resolution high enough for iPhone 6.5", only the iPhone XS Max produced 1242 x 2688 pixels (portrait).

Answer (score 16):

With Xcode 10, iphone 8 plus simulator worked for 5.5inch. Then, Iphone Xs Max for 6.5 inch, but this needed the alpha removed, which can be done by opening the image, clicking 'file' > 'export' and unchecking alpha.

Comment: Iphone Xs Max created an image with 1242 x 2688 for me and I could upload the screenshots directly without any additional handling of the file.

Comment: Superb solution.

Comment: Took a lot of wasted time to figure this out. Thank you for your posting. It saved me from head banging any longer that I already had.

Answer (score 13):

With Xcode 13.4.1, I'm using the following simulators to create screenshots:

- iPhone 13 Pro Max 9 (6.5-inch)
- iPhone 8 Plus (5.5-inch)
- iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation)
- iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)

The other simulators might give you incorrect sizes.

To take the screenshot, use the screenshot button above the simulator or File - Save Screen.

**Edit: updated for Xcode 13.4.1**

Comment: This still works with Xcode 13.0

Comment: With Xcode 13.4.1 i had to use the iPhone 13 Pro Max for the 6.5" Display and iPhone 8 Plus for 5.5" Display

Answer (score 2):

Do not use cmd+4 shortcut, use Simulator -> New Screenshot.

For me, using system shortcut produces bad results, Simulator screenshot works ok.

[image: here]

Answer (score -10):

Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale is a **Simulator** option, open your simulator and proceed to use it

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is not available in XCode Simulator 10.0 .