# Possible to create iOS preview screenshot using simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, appstore-approval

I've tried to run the app on iOS iPad Pro 12.9 inches but the resulted file is with dimension 564 x 748 while the expected dimensions is 2048 x 2732. Other than taking screenshot from real device as I don't have any, wondering if it's possible in anyway to take from simulator instead?

Comment: [Fastlane's snapshot](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take screenshots in the iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092613/take-screenshots-in-the-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a take screenshot option on the top bar! I use it to get screen shots of apps before I put them on the App Store! Or if you’re really desperate, press command + 4 on your Mac and take a computer screenshot then alter the dimensions on a photo editor

Comment: Thanks for sharing that there is such option however the dimension is `1034 × 1380` instead, which doesnt fulfill the dimensions needed as listed at https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Comment: you may just need to photoshop it to fix the dimensions! Or go to a website that will scale it for you (: