# Screen capture Xcode simulator without the top panel?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

In the past, we can capture the Simulator image without the bottom panel using Shift+command+4+space and follow by command+mouseLeftClick as per [this article](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/clean-android-emulator-and-ios-simulator-screen-capture-on-mac-40c7d19dde8e?source=friends_link&sk=a66166c042b3f628d13a0032169e40a7).

However, with the latest Xcode 11.6, the Simulator has a new top panel, and can't be removed during screen capture anymore. Is there a way to remove the top panel without manually use picture editing tool?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the acceptable answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840190/3933094

Comment: I want to capture together with the phone Device Bezel.

Comment: The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840190/3933094 is just to remove the shadow.  The top panel is still there.