# How to take app screenshot to upload appstore?

Tags: xamarin.forms, app-store

I used Xamarin Forms to develop my application and I want to publish it in appstore. I have a problem about simulator's screenshot. I have connected to the my mac device and run the my application. Then, I take the screenshot of the application in my windows device. When I try to upload these screenshots to the appstore, I have a problem with device sizes. I am using iPhone 8 Plus Simulator to get 5.5 inch screenshots but the pixels of the pictures are 621 x 1104. However, appstore requires 1242 x 2208 screenshot dimensions. How to I get these screenshots in my windows device?

Comment: I usually took the screenshot and then edit the image on some image editor, to add device case and put the screenshot inside and by last I set the screen size to the size that apple requires. Also you can use some online service, just google for `App screenshot to AppStore generator`, some of them are free and other are paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem , now i take them from the Simulator in MAC

see here how to do this.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092613/take-screenshots-in-the-ios-simulator#:~:text=Press%20%E2%8C%98%20%2B%20shift%20%2B%204%20%2B,logged%2Din%20user's)%20desktop.
```

Comment: instead of posting an answer that just links to another question, please vote to close as a duplicate instead