# Where do iOS simulator screenshots go?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have taken some screenshots using the iOS simulator. Where can I access these screenshots on the file system of my local machine?

The screenshots are not ending up on my desktop as other responses to similar questions have indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the simulator will generate a thumbnail beside it, you can drop it where you want, if you do nothing, the thumbnail will save to desktop automatically.

Here is a link that may help you
[Take screenshots in the iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092613/take-screenshots-in-the-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 1):

The default screenshot save location is determined by checking these settings in this order. As soon as we find a directory that exists we stop looking.

1. Simulator-specific location. Set with `defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ScreenShotSaveLocation <path_to_directory>`
2. The macOS default screenshot location. Set with `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location <path_to_directory>`
3. The configured Desktop directory for the user, found with URLForDirectory:inDomain
4. If nothing else works, try `$HOME/Desktop`

If you ever set that user default for Simulator or if you configured macOS screen capture to save to a different location that would explain it.

You can always force Simulator to use a folder on your desktop with:
`mkdir ~/Desktop/Screenshots && defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ScreenShotSaveLocation ~/Desktop/Screenshots`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to take a screenshot on Xcode Simulator.

- Through the Simulator's menu bar at the top of the screen: **Device > Trigger Screenshot**. This will take a screenshot as if it were a real device, saving it to the Photos app. This is of no use to you, apparently.
- At the top of the Simulator window itself by pressing the **Save Screen** icon. This will take a "computer-generated" screenshot, allowing you to drag it to a destination right after taking it, such as your computer's Desktop.